# How do you put multiple tkinter widigets into one .grid

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to make a date chooser using python. I am using spinboxes, however I was wondering whether I could get all 5 widgets into one grid space, so it seemed like all 5 widgets are really one widget. Hopefully the following code articulates the problem better.

```
import tkinter as tk

root=tk.Tk()
Day=tk.IntVar()
Month=tk.IntVar()
Year=tk.IntVar()
Label1=tk.Label(root,text="Label Label Label Expanding Row")
Label1.grid(row=1,column=1)

DayEntry=tk.Spinbox(root,textvariable=Day,bg="white",from_=0, to_=31,width=2)
DayEntry.grid(row=2,column=1)
MonthEntry=tk.Spinbox(root,textvariable=Month,bg="white",from_=0, to_=12,width=2)
MonthEntry.grid(row=2,column=3)
YearEntry=tk.Spinbox(root,textvariable=Year,bg="white",from_=2000, to_=20019,width=4)
YearEntry.grid(row=2,column=5)
Divider1=tk.Label(root,text="/")
Divider1.grid(row=2,column=2)
Divider2=tk.Label(root,text="/")
Divider2.grid(row=2,column=4)


root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is to put all of the widgets in a frame.

```
datepicker = tk.Frame(root)
datepicker.grid(row=2, column=0)

DayEntry=tk.Spinbox(datepicker,textvariable=Day,bg="white",from_=0, to_=31,width=2)
MonthEntry=tk.Spinbox(datepicker,textvariable=Month,bg="white",from_=0, to_=12,width=2)
YearEntry=tk.Spinbox(datepicker,textvariable=Year,bg="white",from_=2000, to_=20019,width=4)
Divider1=tk.Label(datepicker,text="/")
Divider2=tk.Label(datepicker,text="/")

DayEntry.grid(row=0,column=1)
Divider1.grid(row=0,column=2)
MonthEntry.grid(row=0,column=3)
Divider2.grid(row=0,column=4)
YearEntry.grid(row=0,column=5)
```